# ASP.NET MVC A problem with routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

how should my Global.asax file look, and the Controller's action, to get a URL like:

```
http://mysite.com/name
```

The `name` is a string - it may be anything.

I try:

Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ViewContent",   // Route name
                "{name}",     // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Main", action = "ViewC" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

MainController:

```
public ActionResult ViewC(string name)
{
    ...
}
```

but it doesn't "go" inside that action.

Comment: What *does* it do instead?  404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{name}",
                    new {.controller = "Main",
                         .action = "ViewC",
                         .name = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

You might also want to make that controller return the view "name"

```
public ActionResult ViewC(string name)
{
    return view(name);
}
```